# Vim VS Code Extension: How to remap "i" in normal mode to Escape key?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

So I want to remap "i" to escape key since i find it easier to remember. But when I do this to settings.json of the VS Code:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
     {
        "before": [
            "i"
        ],
        "after": [
           "<Esc>"
        ]
     }
]
```

The "i" key is disabled and nothing happens. Just the "i" key in insert mode being disabled. Help, I'm new to vim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Vim, the `i` keybinding is used to go into insert mode from normal mode. The `esc` key is usually used to go into normal mode. Setting `i` as `esc` is definitely an anti-pattern. Usually people set `CapsLock` as `esc` key since it's nearer to the home row in keyboard and you don't have to reach as far as `esc` key, and since it's annoying sometimes.
I have also seen some people using `jj` over `esc`.

**Nevertheless, to answer your question, just open `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcut` from command palette(`Ctrl+Shift+p`) and search for `vim_escape`. Then double click on it and enter the key `i` and then press `enter` again. That should get you the desired result.**

Again, suggesting you to not go ahead with this remapping.

Answer (score 0):

open keyboards shortcuts in vscode (ctrl + k, ctrl +s) then search for vim_insert you can change the "i" key to anything that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Came from running VSCode vim keys in windows. [microsoft/Powertoys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases) can remap keys like escape to capslock as in this [tutorial](https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-disable-any-key-on-keyboard-in-windows-11-or-10/) if one was content doing global keyboard mappings like on ubuntu.